# Different behaviour for circular import in submodules of package

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

I am writing a Python package and I am observing different behaviour for circular imports depending on whether I use `from x import y` or `import x.y` in the submodules within the package.

To be clear, I do not want to know how to avoid the circular import, I would just like to understand the behaviour.

My package has the following structure: (`__init__.py` is empty)

```
package/__init__.py
package/module1.py
package/module2.py
```

If I use the `from x import y` form below, then I get an `ImportError` when I try to `import package.module1`.

```
# module1.py
from package import module2

# module2.py
from package import module1
```

However, if I instead use the `import x.y` form, then I can `import package.module1` without any problems. What is going on?

```
# module1.py
import package.module2

# module2.py
import package.module1
```

I have observed this behaviour in Python 2.7.5 and 3.4.3.

**Edit:** There is no error using `from x import y` for versions 3.5.2 and 3.6.4.

Comment: Show please the content of `package/__init__.py`, or is it empty?

Comment: It's empty (edited question to state this).

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this issue, but no luck so far. Can you please confirm that the problem is still here running [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kaduev13/40800e56ecd959f834e951d645e71223)?

Comment: @IvanKalita That gist does reproduce the problem for me.

Comment: I have tried some more python versions and found that the error does **not** occur in python versions 3.5.2 and 3.6.4. (However, it does occur in 2.7.12 and 2.7.14.)